# How can I get previous scene key in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I need to get a previous scene key in componentWillReceiveProps using react-native-router-flux to checkout what screen I come back from and make some action on condition. I looked through a lot but haven`t found an answer. Are there any ways to do that ?

Comment: What is your scenario?

Comment: I've recently answered a question similar to this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507546/5557220). Hope it helps.