# Get previously scene with react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to get the information from the previous page to the current one.

I find this solution, but it doesn't work. Use the property `prevScene` of `Actions` but it return the same string of `currentScente`. Why?

Furthermore, I see this relative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919066/how-can-i-get-previous-scene-key-in-react-native-router-flux), but no one has answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question but I couldn't find the right prop for it.

So I've passed a `from` props while navigating to the currentScene and used it for further processing, like this:

```
Actions.currentSceneKey({ from: 'prevSceneKey' });

console.log(this.props.from); // prevSceneKey
```